# How to fix "the gcc compilation error (sys/ustat.h: no such file or directory) in archlinux?"

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, archlinux

As of now, my archlinux system require current version of gcc (8.3) along with gcc 7.2 and gcc 5.5 (in some other path).

I am trying to compile the source code as below:

```
$ ./contrib/download-prerequisites
```

In build dir:

```
$ ../gcc-5.5.0/configure --prefix=/home/mjonyh/bin/gcc/5.5.0 --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran
```

than found the error

```
sys/ustat.h: no such file or directory
```

Already installed: binutils gcc-libs libmpc gcc-ada libmpc dejagnu inetutils lib32-gcc-libs doxygen gcc-ada lib32-glibc

Update:
I resolve the problem by manually comment out the *ustat.h* in
**gcc-x.x.x/libsanitizer/sanitizer-common/sanitizer-platform-limits-posix.cc** (line number 157 and 250). Because archlinux deprecated the ustat.h in glibc.

Comment: I think you'll need to show us more output. All I can tell from the few lines shown is that *something* failed, causing `make` to report an error. There should be an error message further back showing directly what failed.

Comment: what is that _something_? How can I find that?

Comment: It looks like your error is from `make`, not `configure`, and you didn't show us the `make` command. Running `make` is going to produce a lot of output, including error messages. Save that output to a file, and then look for error messages in that file.

Comment: Thank you all. I have found the problem. It is _sys/ustat.h_ is missing. Since I am using gcc 8.3. Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: Now that you've found the error, please include that information (the error message in the output of `make`) in your question. On my system, that file is provided by the `libc6-dev` package. The name might be different on Arch Linux.

Comment: `ustat.h` has been deprecated in glibc for archlinux. I couldn't find the error message when using `make -j 9`. After using only `make`, it shows the error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: From the `NEWS` file for glibc: "The obsolete function `ustat` is no longer available to newly linked binaries; the headers `<ustat.h>` and `<sys/ustat.h>` have been removed.  This function has been deprecated in favor of `fstatfs` and `statfs`."

Answer (score 1):

The release notes for glibc 2.28 say this:

> - The obsolete function `ustat` is no longer available to newly linked binaries; the headers `<ustat.h>` and `<sys/ustat.h>` have been removed.  This function has been deprecated in favor of `fstatfs` and `statfs`.

In order to build GCC 5.5, you have a few options:

- Build on an older distribution which uses glibc 2.27 or earlier.
- Backport [the fix to the Go frontend](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=261896) to GCC 5.  (`ustat` was added to Go only by accident, its deprecation predates the start of Go development, and perhaps even Google as a company.)
- Disable the gccgo frontend using a suitable `--enable-languages=` argument to the `configure` invocation.

Comment: Since go language is not required by my system, I guess that the “troubleshooting “ I did, will not make a problem. What do you think?

Comment: You can actually have the supported languages by your gcc version with ```configure --enable-languages=showmeplease```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from this:

> Update: I resolve the problem by manually comment out the ustat.h in gcc-x.x.x/libsanitizer/sanitizer-common/sanitizer-platform-limits-posix.cc (line number 157 and 250). Because archlinux deprecated the ustat.h in glibc.

gcc-7.4.0 has removed `ustat.h` in `sanitizer-platform-limits-posix.cc`. Try 7.4.0 instead if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch commit: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/71b55d45e4304f5e2e98ac30473c581f58fc486b

libsanitizer: Use pre-computed size of struct ustat for Linux
Cherry-pick compiler-rt revision 333213:

<sys/ustat.h> has been removed from glibc 2.28 by:

commit cf2478d53ad7071e84c724a986b56fe17f4f4ca7
Author: Adhemerval Zanella adhemerval.zanella@linaro.org
Date:   Sun Mar 18 11:28:59 2018 +0800

```
Deprecate ustat syscall interface
```

This patch uses pre-computed size of struct ustat for Linux.

```
PR sanitizer/85835
* sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc: Don't
include <sys/ustat.h> for Linux.
(SIZEOF_STRUCT_USTAT): New.
(struct_ustat_sz): Use SIZEOF_STRUCT_USTAT for Linux.
```